# How to modify FBSDKLoginButton to have a custom image in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a working FB Login Button using the FBSDKLoginButton in IOS. How can I customize the image of the button?

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize the button that ships with the SDK, however, you are free to build your own button and then call the Login methods of the SDK yourself.

There is a dedicated section for a [custom login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/advanced#custom-login-button) in their documentation.

Comment: The link is outdated